# Совместить два действия при отправки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).find('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // отправка формы по Enter
    }
  });
});

$("#button").click(function() {
  // Отправка формы по клику на кнопку
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как совместить эти два действия, чтобы не повторять код отправки формы

Comment: Поясните подробнее задачу, желательно с рабочим примером. Формы и так обычно отправляются при нажатии Enter и при клике на кнопке. А там, где у вас комментарии, можно вызвать одну и ту же функцию отправки формы.

Comment: Есть такое событие `form.onsubmit` оно заменит два ваших события в одном

Comment: выносите то что у вас под комментами в одну функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще конечно лучше использовать событие формы `onsubmit`, но ситуации бывают разные, может вам нужно что-то такое:

```
function sendForm(){
   // еще какой-то код 
   $('#form').submit()
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).find('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      sendForm();
    }
  });
});

$("#button").click(function() {
  sendForm();
});
```

Этот вопрос скорее закрывает тему о том как не дублировать код, чем работу с формой, но я конечно не знаю всех обстоятельств.